# Scale down image to fit div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to scale down an inage to fit a div container that are greater then the max width and heights set. I have the code below that gets the width and height of the image and the sets max sizes allowed.

This is were I'm out of my depth, the image it loads below is 662x599. The width is greater the the max allowed so I need it to scale down correctly and be placed into the center of the div.

```
var max_width = 713;
var max_height = 550;

var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    img.width = this.width;
    img.height = this.height;
}
img.src = 'files.jpg';
```

Below is an example me resizing the image manually that looks good to give you a rough example of how it should look should. I intent to use styles "top" and "left" to place the image in the center of the div.

```
<img style="width: 613px; height: 550px; top: 0px; left: 50px;" src="files.jpg">
```

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: @undefined I am editing an existing js image slider and want to over write any css applied to it.

Comment: You tagged your post jQuery, but you didn't post any jQuery. Is this correct?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just set the width to 100%?

Comment: @RichBradshaw What if image is smaller then max sizes would that not stretch the image?

Comment: @Mooseman JS or jQuery.

Comment: I might be going about this the wrong way I dont know.

Comment: So, check for that with javascript, and only add width:100%; if needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is code to calculate `width`, `height`, `top`, `left`.

```
// max_width  = 713
// max_height = 550
// img.width  = 662
// img.height = 599

scale_width = max_width / img.width;
scale_height = max_height / img.height;

scale = Math.min(scale_width, scale_height);

width = img.width * scale;  // 608
height = img.height * scale;  // 550

left = (max_width - width)/2; // 52
top = (max_height - height)/2;  // 0
```

Comment: Thanks just what I was after

Comment: btw: this code also increases too small image and keeps the original aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you even need JavaScript? Just set the `max-width` on the image to match that of the containing `div` (i.e., 100%).

http://jsfiddle.net/Pp7Rg/1/

```
<div>
    <img src="https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.photoinpixel.com/mypicture/persian-cat-hd-wallpaper.jpg&ei=dTWZUYHKOoqkiQLto4GYAw&sa=X&oi=unauthorizedredirect&ct=targetlink&ust=1368996989961871&usg=AFQjCNHdsjijJ2oeKrUuvZRMFUuIRxydtg"/>
</div>

div {
    width: 500px;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```